# How to use Java OpenCSV Library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I included a pom.xml file found online for OpenCSV (shown below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi3Mf.png)

I downloaded the recent Java extension to use Maven, then I open Maven

When I try click install on the csvreader file under Maven project, it gives the following error:

> Maven executable not found in PATH. Please specify "maven.executable.path".

How do I fix this error and use the library?

(FYI, I am a beginner to Java, and I really want to use OpenCSV library function)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.quadmeup</groupId>
  <artifactId>csv-reader</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>csv-reader</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You mention you've installed a VS Code extension to work _with_ Maven, but have you actually [installed Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)?

Comment: You might be better off using a real Java IDE like IntelliJ, Eclipse or NetBeans.

Comment: This may have something to do with your maven. Can you show your maven installation?